# How can I vectorize this loop? (Not how do I one-hot encode)

Tags: python, pandas

How can this loop be vectorized?  Or can it?  I just don't see it.

```
for c in cats:
    df[c] = np.where(df['categories'].str.contains(c),1,0)
```

(Before reading the **full story** below, expect that you will be very tempted to answer what appears to be the a one-hot encoding question with `get_dummies(sep=';)`.  But that is not really what I am asking. What I strictly want answered is the question above - about vectorizing that loop. I included the **full story** for context only.)

**The full story:**

```
d = {'categories': ['catA;catB;catC','catA;catB','catC','catB;catC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

       categories
0  catA;catB;catC
1       catA;catB
2            catC
3       catB;catC

cats = ['catA','catB','catC']

for c in cats:
    df[c] = np.where(df['categories'].str.contains(c),1,0)
    
print(df)

       categories  catA  catB  catC
0  catA;catB;catC     1     1     1
1       catA;catB     1     1     0
2            catC     0     0     1
3       catB;catC     0     1     1
```

Comment: What is the usecase? I am assuming because you may have more strings in different formats but you want to just match the strings in `cat` ? in that case you can do `df['categories'].str.findall('|'.join(cats)).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()` get_dummies again:D

Comment: @anky - yeah I get it.  Great answer.  Maybe my question is more simplistic.  In striving to go from loop -> apply -> vectorize I was really trying to see if the loop with `np.where()` could be vectorized.  You did got it done but did not use `np.where()`.  Maybe it can't be done with `np.where()`.  Why don't you throw your solution into an answer.  I will mark as solved and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I understood from the question and gathered from comments. you are not looking for get_dummies since you may have a larger string not necessarily seperated by the `;`. In that case its better that you use **[`series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)** to return the values which match strings in  `cat`. Then you can either join them and use **[`str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)** or **[`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)**:

```
cats = ['catA','catB','catC']
s=df['categories'].str.findall('|'.join(cats))
```

Fast method:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
out1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),
         columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index))
```

using `series.str.get_dummies()`

```
out2 = df.join(s.str.join("|").str.get_dummies())
```

---

```
print((out1==out2).all().all())
#True
```

---

```
print(out1)

       categories  catA  catB  catC
0  catA;catB;catC     1     1     1
1       catA;catB     1     1     0
2            catC     0     0     1
3       catB;catC     0     1     1
```